# multiple if statement with different conditions

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I try to check user input on my `EditText`, if there's one or more null value, the validation image will be changed into red color and it the page will be not moved until all field is filled. I'm using multiple if statement with different conditions in my case but
I get a problem, when I input into two `EditText` and another `EditText` is null, the page move from current page into new page, when it should not be moved. 
this is my code :

```
if (nama_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){img_namalengkap_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);}
            if (ibu_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){img_namaibu_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);}
            if (nomor_bukti_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){img_nomeridentitas_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);}
            if (tempat_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){img_tempat_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);}
            if (ttl_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){img_tgllahir_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);}
            if (alamat_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){img_alamat_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);}
            if (kota_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){img_kota_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);}
            if (kdtlp1_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){img_telepon_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);}
            if (telp1_pp.getText().toString().length()==0){img_telepon_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);}
else {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new TertanggungPolis()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
}
```

is there  a faster way to code things like that and the best solution for my problem? thank you very much.

Comment: Just a tip: use Android API's `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)` to check if it's null or empty.

Comment: looks like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com to me. Because your code works, you just want to optimize.

Comment: @donfuxx close enough, but the code itself has an issue with the last `if-block` (wrong logic). I assume Code Review only accepts working and correct code?

Comment: Ok, if there is also a bug then it is fine here ;-)

Comment: @AndrewT.thank you for your tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the edit text in one array list and the corresponding image views in another one.

For empty string we can use, `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)` which returns true if the string is null or empty.

Try this:

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();

editTexts.add(nama_pp);
editTexts.add(editetext2);

ArrayList<ImageView> imageViews =  new ArrayList<ImageView>();
imageViews.add(image1);
imageVioew.add(Image2);

boolean nextPage = true;

for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.length();i++) 
    if (editText[i].isEmpty(editText[i].getText.toString())) {
        imageViews[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);
        nextPage = false;
    }
}
```

Before moving to next page , You can check something like this:

```
if (nextPage) {
//Move to next page
}
```

Comment: Would you care to explain your code at all and *why* it should be used?

Comment: @ZohraKhan my problem is not only a faster way for make my code more simple, , when I input into two EditText and another EditText is null, the page move from current page into new page, when it should not be moved

Comment: Hi @ZohraKhan can u come in Android Coders chat room..??

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your objects in a list, and iterate through that list like so:

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<>(9);

editTexts.add(nama_pp);
editTexts.add(...);
boolean ready = true;
for (EditText editText : editTexts)
    if (editText.getText().toString().length() == 0) { ready = false; break; }
if (ready)
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new TertanggungPolis()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
else img_telepon_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);
```

It's less typing at least.

Sebastien Bianchi's idea is a good, also.

Comment: i have different name for `ImageView` if I'm using your way, I think its only can for the `EditText` with same `ImageView`, but I think your Idea with give `boolean` logic, is good, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

It's moving to the next page because your `else` is only matched up with the last `if`. So as long as the last `if` test fails, it will transition to the next page.

A simple fix would be to replace all but the first `if` statement with `else if`:

```
if (condition1) { 
} else if (condition2) { 
} else {
    getFragmentManager() ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it more readable by using `||` and creating an `isEmpty()` method:

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText et) {
    return et.getText().toString().length() == 0;
}
```

then

```
if (isEmpty(ibu_pp) || isEmpty(nomor_bukti_pp) || ...  ) {
    img_telepon_pp.setImageResource(R.drawable.espaj_red_checklist);
}
```

Comment: i have different name for `ImageView` if I'm using your way, I think its only can for the `EditText` with same `ImageView`

Comment: Then you can separate in different if blocks, but there is not much more you can do that making it more readable.

Comment: yup, thats what I do before, I separate it in different if blocks.

Answer (score 0):

why not add a textWatcher？ It's more objective.you dont need to conside the condition, you just ask each EditText is your input is valid.less work, more expansibility.You will never bothered there are so many edittexts